# Why can't I see a background image set with bootstrap CSS, but can see external image resource?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I'm writing a Rails application using Bootstrap. I want to set an image background for it, which I've done using an `override.css.scss` file. The background displays white when looking at my image, which is in the `app/assets/images/` folder.

if I set the image to an external resource, it displays fine.

CSS in override with local image:

```css
html, body {
    padding-top: 60px;
    background-image: url('app/assets/images/nyc.png');
    /* background-repeat: no-repeat; */
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 1000px;

}
```

CSS in override with external image:

```css
html, body {
    padding-top: 60px;
    background-image: url('http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png');
    /* background-repeat: no-repeat; */
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 1000px; 
}
```

Baffling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relative URLs in CSS are relative to the to the CSS file, so perhaps you are pointing to the wrong location?

```
/path/to/app/assets/images/nyc.png
/path/to/style.css
```

Unless your CSS file lives here, relative to the file in question, you'll be getting a 404 on that image.